# How do I remove rows from a product table in woocommerce email templates?

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, gravity

I am using woocommerce and gravity forms product addons.

The email template creates a table with rows including all the options a customer selects.

I just need to remove one row.

Please help. The image below shows which row I am want to remove.

[image]

Comment: pls share the code which you have written for modifying email template content.

Comment: Hi, I haven't written any code. That's the default.

Comment: then any 3rd part plugin will be overwriting it, because by default WooCommerce does not output such serialized string in email template.

Answer (score 2):

You can find anything related to WooCommerce e-mails and changing the templates here:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/custom-email-templates/

Comment: I might give that a try. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to the same thing as OP @anhtonyt  anybody got a filename and code to change it? I tried but failed. I will have to post the same question again, but this time with a bit more effort given than OP. and template editing guide you linked to is terrible, with very little examples given.